# Dual booting Ubuntu And Windows 10 (Both of separate ssd) and swap space

Tags: dual-boot, windows, ssd, programming

I currently have 1 SSD and 1 TB HDD. In my SSD, I have Windows 10 and programs installed. HDD is where I have all my files.

I have recently bought a new SSD and I am planning to install Ubuntu on it development purposes. And I would like to dual boot Windows 10 along side Ubuntu.

My plan is to have 1 SSD for Windows, 1 SSD for Ubuntu, and use the 1 TB HDD to store some files from both operating systems.

The new SSD I got is ADATA Premier SP550 120GB.

So should I just install Ubuntu on my new SSD? Then set the SSD that runs Win 10 to be my primary booting device, and then use EasyBCD to make the dual boot menu?

Also, how much swap space should I choose for Ubuntu? 3GB perhaps?
I am going to be doing a lot of programming on linux. I will also be using a lot Intellij IDEA and they are resource heavy.

Is there anything else that I should know for better performance and to prolong the longevity of my hardware?

Thanks.

Other information:
Computer: Dell Optiplex 755,
Graphics Card: nVidia GTX 650,
Ram: 8GB DDR2

Answer (score 1):

If I were you I would make Ubuntu SSD primary booting device. In the process of the Ubuntu installation it will catch automatically other operating systems and will put them in its boot loader - **Grub2**. There is easy to use GUI interface for future edit of Grub boot loader configuration - called **[Grub customizer](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2016/04/install-grub-customizer-ubuntu-16-04-lts/)**.

I would make the swap double sized of the physical RAM.

Yes, there is some Ubuntu optimizations of SSD uses, but I don't have SSD, and I never tried these optimizations.

Answer (score 0):

I had windows 10 and ubuntu 12/14/15/16.04 in Dualboot, when I changed my hybrid disk to SSD and win 8.1 it works like a charm.

Windows 10 will take over your managment, there is a workaround for updates but then you cannot even install a printer :/

swap space ubuntu: same ora bit more then your memory.

I have a Lenovo Yoga 500-15ISK 80R6005BGE, uefi, NV940 und intelHD. I have now backlight-indicator installed due to not working brightness.